# I am reading specific numbers from a large file and writing them to more large files is there a way to decrease computing time?

Tags: python, performance, file

I have a code that reads a large file (200 000 kB). Basically what i need to do is compare two lines at a time and write the difference between the numbers on line n and line n-1 to a new file. Now im writing it to three new files for neutron, electron and photon ('pisi' function).

My question is is there anything in my code that can be done more efficiently as it takes around 2 hours for my code to process 7 files ( and I have about 200)?

In case it is not clear what I am doing:

- I open a file (that is as in example)
- I read a line remember it, read next line, do operations on this two lines, forget first line and make second line my oldline and repeat this till the end of file.
- Now the operations from oldline and newline are written to three different files depending on some not important factor.

I'm not experienced in python time management I have always just brute forced everything so any help would be welcome!

Code here: ('pisi' is to write what i want in files, 'uporabno' is a bunch of if clauses that uses 'pisi' when conditions are met)

```
def pisi(delc,oldline,newline,DeltaE,procent): #write to file
    if delc==1.0:
        with open('Nevtroni%i.txt' %procent, 'a+') as f:
            E1 = float(oldline[-2])  # E1
            X = float(oldline[-9]) - float(newline[-9])  # delta x
            Y = float(oldline[-8]) - float(newline[-8])  # delta y
            Z = float(oldline[-7]) - float(newline[-7])  # delta z
            Part = float(oldline[-1])
            if DeltaE>0:
                f.write('%s' % DeltaE + ' ' + '%s' % E1 + ' ' + '%s' % X + ' ' + '%s' % Y + ' ' + '%s' % Z + ' ' + '%s' % Part)
                f.write('\n')
        f.close()
    if delc==2.0:
        with open('Fotoni%i.txt' %procent, 'a+') as f:
            E1 = float(oldline[-2])  # E1
            X = float(oldline[-9]) - float(newline[-9])  # delta x
            Y = float(oldline[-8]) - float(newline[-8])  # delta y
            Z = float(oldline[-7]) - float(newline[-7])  # delta z
            Part = float(oldline[-1])
            if DeltaE>0:
                f.write('%s' % DeltaE + ' ' + '%s' % E1 + ' ' + '%s' % X + ' ' + '%s' % Y + ' ' + '%s' % Z + ' ' + '%s' % Part)
                f.write('\n')
        f.close()
    if delc==3.0:
        with open('Elektroni%i.txt' %procent, 'a+') as f:
            E1 = float(oldline[-2])  # E1
            X = float(oldline[-9]) - float(newline[-9])  # delta x
            Y = float(oldline[-8]) - float(newline[-8])  # delta y
            Z = float(oldline[-7]) - float(newline[-7])  # delta z
            Part = float(oldline[-1])
            if DeltaE>0:
                f.write('%s' % DeltaE + ' ' + '%s' % E1 + ' ' + '%s' % X + ' ' + '%s' % Y + ' ' + '%s' % Z + ' ' + '%s' % Part)
                f.write('\n')
        f.close()
```

```
def uporabno(fname,a):
    with open(fname) as infile:
        oldline=None

        for line in infile:
            newline = line.strip().split(' ')  # ev:# event_type mat cell_no x y z vx vy vz weight E particle_type
            if oldline is not None:
                    #if reads specific things i want from fname all are similar
                if newline[1] == 'COL' and oldline[1]=='SUR':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    if newline[0] != 'ev:1':
                        pisi(float(oldline[-1]), oldline, newline, DeltaE,a)
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'BNK' and oldline[1]=='SUR':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    if oldline[-10]==newline[-10] and newline[0] != 'ev:1': #if BNK happens in same material
                        pisi(float(oldline[-1]), oldline, newline, DeltaE,a)
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'TER' and oldline[1]=='SUR':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    if newline[0] !='ev:1':
                        pisi(float(oldline[-1]), oldline, newline, DeltaE,a)
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'COL' and oldline[1]=='COL':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    if newline[0] != 'ev:1':
                        pisi(float(oldline[-1]), oldline, newline, DeltaE,a)
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'SUR' and oldline[1]=='COL':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    #skip as not consecutive events, just means particle crossed surface after colision
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'BNK' and oldline[1]=='COL':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    if oldline[-10] == newline[-10] and newline[0] != 'ev:1':  # if BNK happens in same material
                        pisi(float(oldline[-1]), oldline, newline, DeltaE,a)
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'TER' and oldline[1]=='COL':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    if oldline[-10] == newline[-10] and newline[0] !='ev:1':  # if BNK happens in same material
                        pisi(float(oldline[-1]), oldline, newline, DeltaE,a)
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'TER' and oldline[1]=='BNK':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    if oldline[-10] == newline[-10] and newline[0] != 'ev:1' and float(oldline[-2])<1:  # same material, not nev event, energija manša od Mev ker drugac ne razumemo
                        pisi(float(oldline[-1]), oldline, newline, DeltaE,a)
                    oldline=newline #read      #
                if newline[1] == 'SUR' and oldline[1]=='BNK':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    #skip as not event, just means particle crossed surface.
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'COL' and oldline[1]=='BNK':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    if oldline[-10] == newline[-10] and newline[0] != 'ev:1':  # if BNK happens in same material
                        pisi(float(oldline[-1]), oldline, newline, DeltaE,a)
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'BNK' and oldline[1]=='TER':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    #skip for electrons
                    if oldline[-10] == newline[-10] and newline[0] !='ev:1' and float(newline[-1]) != 3.0: # if BNK happens in same material
                        pisi(float(oldline[-1]), oldline, newline, DeltaE,a)
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'COL' and oldline[1]=='TER':
                    DeltaE = float(oldline[-2]) - float(newline[-2])
                    if oldline[-10] == newline[-10] and newline[0] != 'ev:1':  # if BNK happens in same material
                        pisi(float(oldline[-1]), oldline, newline, DeltaE,a)
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'SUR' and oldline[1]=='TER':
                    #skip since surface is not event.
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'SUR' and oldline[1]=='SUR':
                    #skip
                    oldline=newline
                if newline[1] == 'BNK' and oldline[1]=='BNK':
                    #skip
                    oldline=newline
            else:
                oldline=newline
```

Comment: I think this could be rewritten using pandas to become much faster but this would be a task too large for a question on this site.

Comment: You're opening a closing files every iteration of the loop which is disastrous for the performance of your code. I would suggest creating a _default dict_ of either lists of strings or StringIO buffers. The keys would be the filenames (e.g. `'Nevtroni%i.txt' %procent`). After the main for loop, iterate over this dict and write it to file. Also, I suspect all those if statements could be turned into if-else-if statements. Significant improvements can be made to your code without even using pandas, as suggested by _Michael Butscher_.

Comment: As an aside, note that there's no need to call `f.close()` because the `with` blocks will do this automatically.

Comment: Thank you @GordonAitchJay. If you have any pointers for dict and StringIO that would be awesome as i have no clue what that means

Comment: I'll post an answer tomorrow when I have time to explain it. By using a `defaultdict` of `StringIO` buffers that are only written to disk at the end, I was able to reduce the time of processing a 200 MB file from 720.6 seconds to just 4.4 seconds.

Comment: Okay thanks thats exactly what i want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening and closing files takes a relatively long time. It's best to keep all the data you want to write to file in memory, and then at the end open and write the data to file in one go.

[`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) is an in-memory text buffer. You can write to it as if it was a text file opened with the mode `a+`, but it never writes any data to disk. Its buffer needs to be explicitly written to disk at the end.

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a dict that creates a new key, value pair if the dict is accessed with a key that doesn't yet exist. In this case, the default value will be a new `StringIO` buffer, and the key will be a filename.

There is a lot of unnecessary repetition in your implementation of `pisi`. There's no need to write the same code 3 times within each if statement when the only difference is the filename.

I have used [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) instead of *string interpolation* (strings with %) because, imo, it is easier to read and more concise.

Processing a 200 MB file for me went from 720.6 seconds to just 4.4 seconds.

```py
def pisi(delc, oldline, newline, delta_e, percent): # write to file
    e1 = oldline[-2] # E1
    x = float(oldline[-9]) - float(newline[-9]) # delta x
    y = float(oldline[-8]) - float(newline[-8]) # delta y
    z = float(oldline[-7]) - float(newline[-7]) # delta z
    part = oldline[-1]
    
    if delta_e > 0:
        if delc == 1.0:
            filename = f'Nevtroni{percent}.txt'
        elif delc == 2.0:
            filename = f'Fotoni{percent}.txt'
        elif delc == 3.0:
            filename = f'Elektroni{percent}.txt'
        
        # buffer is a defaultdict of StringIO objects defined at the global scope
        buffers[filename].write(f'{delta_e} {e1} {x} {y} {z} {part}\n')

# uporabno remains the same

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from shutil import copyfileobj
import time

start = time.process_time()

# The actual StringIO object will be created when the dict is first accessed 
# with a new key (filename)
buffers = defaultdict(StringIO)

# Process the input file
uporabno('physics200.txt', 100)

# Iterate over the buffers and write (append) them to the correspoding files
for filename, buffer in buffers.items():
    with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
        # Since we've been writing to the buffer, the stream position will be 
        # at the end. Move it to the start before writing it to file
        buffer.seek(0)
        copyfileobj(buffer, f)

print("Total duration:", time.process_time() - start)
```

---

Here's another implementation with a lot of changes that significantly reduces the repetition of your code, doesn't use global variables, and makes it easier to read by using constants to index into `oldline` and `newline`. It now only takes 3.9 seconds.

By defining `pisi` within `uporabno`, `pisi` no longer needs arguments, as it can access the variables defined in `uporabno` (enclosed scope).

Indexing directly into a list with numbers (and negative numbers) makes it inscrutable to read. I'm fairly certain you were off by one in some instances, too. Instead, use constants with meaningful names that refer to the value you're accessing.

There's a glaring bug in your original code, too. Having `oldline=newline` at the end of every if statement, means the following if statements are no longer comparing 2 different lines. They are now the same line. The new line should only become the old line at the end of the loop, after all the if statements.

I would double check the code very closely to ensure it's doing what you intend. If not, your output files are totally misleading.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from shutil import copyfileobj
from time import time

def uporabno(fname, procent):
    def pisi():
        """Writes values to the right StringIO buffer"""
        
        delc = oldline[PARTICLE_TYPE]
        delta_e = oldline[E] - newline[E]
        e1 = oldline[E] # E1
        x = float(oldline[X]) - float(newline[X]) # delta x
        y = float(oldline[Y]) - float(newline[Y]) # delta y
        z = float(oldline[Z]) - float(newline[Z]) # delta z
        part = oldline[PARTICLE_TYPE]
        if delta_e > 0:
            if delc == 1.0:
                filename = f'Nevtroni{procent}.txt'
            elif delc == 2.0:
                filename = f'Fotoni{procent}.txt'
            elif delc == 3.0:
                filename = f'Elektroni{procent}.txt'
            
            # buffer is a defaultdict of StringIO objects
            buffers[filename].write(f'{delta_e} {e1} {x} {y} {z} {part}\n')
    
    # The actual StringIO object will be created when the dict is first accessed 
    # with a new key (filename)
    buffers = defaultdict(StringIO)
    
    # Offsets of attributes into the split lines
    # ev:# event_type mat cell_no x y z vx vy vz weight E particle_type
    # (look away PEP 8 devotees, whitespace used for alignment ahead!)
    EV            =  0 # -13
    EVENT_TYPE    =  1 # -12
    MAT           =  2 # -11
    CELL_NO       =  3 # -10
    X             =  4 # -9
    Y             =  5 # -8
    Z             =  6 # -7
    VX            =  7 # -6
    VY            =  8 # -5
    VZ            =  9 # -4
    WEIGHT        = 10 # -3
    E             = 11 # -2
    PARTICLE_TYPE = 12 # -1
    
    with open(fname) as infile:
        oldline = None
        for line in infile:
            newline = line.strip().split()
            
            # These two values are transformed to float frequently, so do it 
            # once up front now.
            newline[E] = float(newline[E])
            newline[PARTICLE_TYPE] = float(newline[PARTICLE_TYPE])
            
            if oldline is not None:
                # if reads specific things i want from fname all are similar
                if newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'COL' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'SUR':
                    if newline[EV] != 'ev:1':
                        pisi()
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'BNK' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'SUR':
                    #if BNK happens in same material
                    if oldline[MAT]==newline[MAT] and newline[EV] != 'ev:1':
                        pisi()
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'TER' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'SUR':
                    if newline[EV] !='ev:1':
                        pisi()
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'COL' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'COL':
                    if newline[EV] != 'ev:1':
                        pisi()
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'SUR' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'COL':
                    pass # skip as not consecutive events, just means particle crossed surface after colision
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'BNK' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'COL':
                    # if BNK happens in same material
                    if oldline[MAT] == newline[MAT] and newline[EV] != 'ev:1':
                        pisi()
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'TER' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'COL':
                    # if BNK happens in same material
                    if oldline[MAT] == newline[MAT] and newline[EV] !='ev:1':
                        pisi()
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'TER' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'BNK':
                    # same material, not nev event, energija manša od Mev ker drugac ne razumemo
                    if oldline[MAT] == newline[MAT] and newline[EV] != 'ev:1' and oldline[E] < 1:
                        pisi()
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'SUR' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'BNK':
                    pass # skip as not event, just means particle crossed surface.
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'COL' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'BNK':
                    # if BNK happens in same material
                    if oldline[MAT] == newline[MAT] and newline[EV] != 'ev:1':
                        pisi()
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'BNK' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'TER':
                    # skip for electrons
                    # if BNK happens in same material
                    if oldline[MAT] == newline[MAT] and newline[EV] !='ev:1' and newline[PARTICLE_TYPE] != 3.0: 
                        pisi()
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'COL' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'TER':
                    # if BNK happens in same material
                    if oldline[MAT] == newline[MAT] and newline[EV] != 'ev:1':
                        pisi()
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'SUR' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'TER':
                    pass # skip since surface is not event.
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'SUR' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'SUR':
                    pass # skip
                elif newline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'BNK' and oldline[EVENT_TYPE] == 'BNK':
                    pass # skip
                
                oldline = newline
            else:
                oldline = newline
    
    # Iterate over the buffers and write (append) them to the correspoding files
    for filename, buffer in buffers.items():
        with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
            # Since we've been writing to the buffer, the stream position will 
            # be at the end. Move it to the start before writing it to file
            buffer.seek(0)
            copyfileobj(buffer, f)

start = time()
uporabno('physics200.txt', 100)
print(time() - start)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this indeed works. Computation time is now 10 seconds instead of 2+ hours! Appreciate it